# Show all data from mysql column by "ALL" word

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have listbox just like this

```
<select id="brand">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Acer">Acer</option>
<option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
</select>
```

And when i choose "Acer" then it is fine works (also Alcatel). But how can I add "all" option to select all brands to show.I wrote following PHP code.But it is not works.How can I create php code for "All" word

```
$dbClass = new Database();

$extraQuery = "";
$subcategories = json_decode($_POST['subcategories']);

if (!empty($subcategories)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($subcategories); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($subcategories[$i]); $j++) {
            if ($i == 0 && $j == 0) {

                $stmt = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE brand=:brand");
                $stmt->execute(array(":brand" => $subcategories[$i][$j]));
                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                    $first = "brand";

                    if ($subcategories[$i][$j] === "All") {
                        $stmt = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE $first like '%'");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $first = $stmt;
                    }

                    $extraQuery = "WHERE (" . $extraQuery . $first . " = " . "'" . $subcategories[$i][$j] . "'";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$first mean there has more columns i have and want set them "All" word

Answer (score 0):

You can set all value to nothing :

```
<select id="brand">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="Acer">Acer</option>
    <option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
</select>
```

Then you can add a where clause in you query only if brand is not empty :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_posts';
$bind = array();

if(!empty($brand)){
    $sql .= ' WHERE brand = :brand';
    $bind[':brand'] = $brand;
}

$stmt = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($bind);
```

Some tuning will be needed to suit your need

Comment: <option value="All"> is not changed. Because it is getting from javascript array. 2 conditions is there. <option value="All"> or <option value="0"> .What should I do?